# How to redirect to an app in store with the older name ?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

I have a question,

I have an app on the store, I'm going to change his name, I just wanted to know how's the redirection is gonna works on the store. I mean, when the users are going to looks for the older app in the SearchBar and writing the older name of the app, will it show automatically the new one with the new name ?

I saw that brand and companies who changed their app title, if I'm looking for the older name, it automatically show me the new one...

Any ideas about the process, how it works, how to manage it ?

Thankkks !

Comment: Keep application Id of gradle same. Just change the app name in Manifest.xml and upload it to Play store again

Comment: Same for iOS ? Don t change the package name but only the displayName ?

Comment: Sorry .. Don't know much about iOS

Comment: @Mayoul Changing only package name in iOS doesn't work for me..i didn't get any solution yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I did both change on iOS Store and Android Store, thought it would have been great to share my experience, since it nicely working now.

The problem was that I needed to modify the name of my app, but keeping the ratings and reviews. If you want to achieve that, you need to keep your bundle Identifier like `mobile.YourEnterprise.com`.

⚠️ if you change your Bundle Identifier, it's gonna apparently create a new application, completely blank.

---

### **iOS**

You can easily modify directly from `itunes.connect` your `displayAppName` in the store. Just go in `MyApp/App Store/Name` and change it. Nothing else to do for the iOS store, ezpz.

Concerning the `appName` on the phone : open your project on Xcode, then select your target `General/display Name` and here too it's just that. Quite simple finally.

I didn't change the bundle Identifier, so there's still the older appName on the BundleIdentifier, and the redirection works like a charm if I write the older name on the iOS Store.

Answer (score 1):

**build.gradle (Module: app)**

```
android {    
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.myappname" //do not change this
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1      //update this
        versionName "1.0" //update this
    }
```

**In Manifest.xml**

```
    <application  android:label="@string/app_name"> //change app name here

      //your activities and services

    </application>
```

Then create the **Signed apk** using **same .jks file** that you used previously.